# Calling Internal Functions Inside Object

Tags: javascript, function, object

Hopefully, this is a simple answer.  I am trying to call a method from inside my object, however, the console is throwing an error that the function is not a function.

```
function tabs(el, data){
    this.el = el;

    this.addTab = function(data){
        console.log("addTab", this.el, data);
    };

    data.forEach(function(data){
        this.addTab(data);
    });
}
```

I am calling my object initially like so:

```
var t = new tabs("tabs", []);
```

My error is that addTab is not a function.

Answer (score 1):

Each function has it's own context which `this` inside it refers to. The context of the function which you have passed to the `forEach` does not refer to the object itself. So you need to keep the context of your function to refer to the current object. Change the function declaration with **[arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)** to preserve the outer context.

```
function tabs(el, data){
    this.el = el;

    this.addTab = function(data){
        console.log("addTab", this.el, data);
    };

    data.forEach((data) => {
        this.addTab(data);
    });
}
```

Comment: An explanation as to *why* that makes a difference would make this a better answer.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I was not aware of the additional features of arrow functions.  I'm wondering though why using addTab (and not this.addTab) from inside the original code also will not work?

Comment: Because `addTab` is bounded to the current object. So you need to find that object than call `addTab` from it

Comment: I see now.  I've set a var self = this in the original tabs function, then called self.addTab instead of this.addTab or arrow function and looks to be working.

Comment: Yes, the `magic :D` is under the `this` keyword, because it is served keyword. With another name you can force to work